# If Statements not Targeting Intended Screen Widths

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some javascript being fired when the screen reaches certain widths... I am trying to make it mobile responsive and need it to fire at different points on different devices...

```
var screenWidth = window.innerWidth;

if (screenWidth <= 812 && screenWidth > 414) {
   $(window).scroll(function() {

     var fromTopPxFirstBgChange = 2300;
     var scrolledFromtop = $(window).scrollTop();

     if (scrolledFromtop > fromTopPxFirstBgChange) {
       $('body').addClass('secondBg');
     }
     else {
       $('body').removeClass('secondBg');
     }
   });
}

if (screenWidth <= 414 && screenWidth > 375) {
   $(window).scroll(function() {

     var changeBg = 2190;
     var scrolledFromtop = $(window).scrollTop();

     if (scrolledFromtop > changeBg) {
       $('body').addClass('secondBg');
     }
     else {
       $('body').removeClass('secondBg');
     }
   });
}

if (screenWidth <= 375 && screenWidth > 320) {
   $(window).scroll(function() {

     var changeBgImage = 2380;
     var scrolledFromtop = $(window).scrollTop();

     if (scrolledFromtop > changeBgImage) {
       $('body').addClass('secondBg');
     }
     else {
       $('body').removeClass('secondBg');
     }
   });
 }
```

So for the first one for example, I would like the screen to apply those changes at 414-812px.

Basically the background image is supposed to change when I am scrolled to the position on the page that I specified in each if statement (the class "secondBg" is a class I specified in the CSS with the new background image...  I don't know if this is a JS error or a problem with other code.  It seems to work uniform when I just have one if statement but when I add the three they sort of work and overwrite one another.  I think the if statements are pretty clear and cannot see the problem.

Comment: Well that code does not magically update when the screen width changes. It runs only when the page loads. So those functions will only be what it is when the device loads the first time. Might be better off adding the logic inside the scroll code OR rebind the methods when the page is resized.

Comment: I understand that logic but it does change as I decrease the screen width... But if I am on a fixed screen those changes are not being applied.  I know this because I had everything looking good on all but one width, and I added another if statement and it seemed to break all the changes I made on the other ones.

Comment: Well you really should be using `if /else if()` so you are not doing all the checks when one passes. In the end your code really should just set a variable and use that variable since you have the same code copy and pasted all over. That is code smell when the code repeats.

Comment: `var defOffset = 2300;  if (){ defOffset =  2190; } else if (){ defOffset =  2380; } window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {  console.log(defOffset); })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be binding your listeners inside the if statements. You should instead have 1 listener and do checks inside like so:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() < 500) {
    // Your code here
  }
  // add more checks here
});
```

Also, I'd throttle that as it's a really heavy operation. Take a look at [this](https://lodash.com/docs#throttle).

Comment: That makes sense.  Thank you.  I applied that and it is working better.  I have heard of throttle a few times I will definitely read up on that, thank you.  At which point, just in general, would you consider throttling?  I guess what are some golden opportunities to do so... just for some context here in more professional situations.  If you have had any situations of your own arise of course.

Comment: Throttle is useful when, like in this case, you call something too many times but don't need to. With the example I gave you, due to the way the scroll listener works the function you provide to it will be executed every pixel scrolled. That isn't necessary so throttle makes sure it can only be called 1 time per specified period, thus saving some processing resource. Also if my answer was helpful and thoroughly answered your question consider accepting it.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  Gave you the acceptance on the answer.